# UINavigationController (drawRect:)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created an application with a TabBarController, 4 TabBarItems and every TabBarItem have is own NavigationController file (everything created in IB).

I'm using the drawRect function to design my navigationBar:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customImage)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)];

}

@end
```

The problem is that the NavigationBar change for every ViewController inside my app, what I want is only draw the NavigationBar for one TabBarItem only and use the default navigationBar for other controller.
How to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

He take me a long time but I fins a solution. by using swizzling method I can do whatever I want.
Look at this [link](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling) for more information on how to implement it.

Comment: any chance you could post the actual code you used to swizzle the drawRect method for a particular controller?

Comment: I got rejected for using swizzling method, it is no longer valid solution

Answer (score 0):

Using a category is probably not the best idea in this case (if you override `drawRect:` using a category, all `UINavigationController`s will be affected).  You'd be better off subclassing UINavigationController, and using the custom subclass only in the tab that you want.

**Edit:**  Subclassing UINavigationController is fairly easy:

(in the .h file)

```
@interface MyCustomNavigationController : UINavigationController {
}
@end
```

(in the .m file)

```
@implementation MyCustomNavigationController

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //custom drawing here
}
@end
```

Then, use `MyCustomNavigationController` instead of `UINavigationController` in your code where appropriate.  Categories (which you used in the sample) are good for adding convenience methods to existing classes, but can be dangerous when replacing already-existing methods (since your custom method will replace the original for all uses).

Comment: ok but how can I subclass the NavigationController and draw the navigationBar inside? I think thats the best idea but I don't knwo how to do it. Do you have some code?

Comment: I already do that, because like I said I use IB and I have subclass every navigationController like this. but it seems that the drawRect is not called.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that you were adding a category to UINavigationBar, rather than UINavigationController (`drawRect:` won't be called for UINavigationController).  Unfortunately, UINavigationBar and UINavigationController aren't very flexible in this regard (you can't set the navigation bar of a navigation controller).  You might be better off using a custom UIToolbar (I found a quick tutorial at http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/09/navigation-controller-uitoolbar.html).  Otherwise, you can try adding the image as one of the items of the navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I can't use a UIToolBar, I need in each of my ViewController a custom UInavigationBar. there must be a way to draw the NavigationBar for each of them, I have to fint it

Comment: you cannot subclass UINavigationBar